# Denjoy's Counterexample for $C^1$ Diffeomorphism of $S^1$

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, diffeomorphism

I am looking for highly recommended references on **Denjoy's Counterexample for $C^1$ Diffeomorphism of $S^1$**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/8AE82D8D19EBD68D0A10240EA439A04C/S0143385700001243a.pdf/c_denjoy_counterexample.pdf) is one for a $\mathcal C^\infty$ counterexample

Comment: @AlephBeth if the function is $C^2$ diffeomorphism with irrational rotation number, it is then conjugate to a rotation. How could this be done for $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Not diffeomorphism, just $\mathcal C^\infty$ (no claimed regularity on the inverse): "_In this paper we construct an example of a homeomorphism of the circle
onto itself which is $\mathcal C^\infty$, has no periodic points and no dense orbits. Moreover, the
homeomorphism will have no more than two points of zero derivative._"